# Converting URL to AVAsset - Swift

Tags: swift, string, swift3, xcode8, avaudioplayer

I am attempting to convert the url that is in my audio player to an AVAsset so that I am able to manipulate the audio track to my liking. ( I just want to be able to trim the file). Unfortunately I am running into an issue where the asset is not correctly converting. When I print the duration of the audio url before I convert it, it will correctly print out the duration. Unfortunately when I convert it to the AVAsset, it says the duration is 0. What is going on? Any guidance would be much appreciated!

```
func trimmingFunc() {

        try? audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: audioURL!)
        passingTime = audioPlayer.duration
        audioPlayer.delegate = self


        let currentDuration = audioPlayer.duration
        print(currentDuration) //correctly prints duration
        let filePath = URL(fileURLWithPath: (("\(String(describing: audioPlayer.url!))")))
        print(filePath) //correctly prints filePath


        let currentAsset = AVAsset(url: filePath)
        print(CMTimeGetSeconds(currentAsset.duration) //This is printing 0

}
```

Comment: `Because of the nature of timed audiovisual media, upon successful initialization of an asset some or all of the values for its keys may not be immediately available.` (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avasset)

Comment: so does that mean I would need to calculate the duration & trim/manipulate my audio file in the completion handler? B/C what I have seen from multiple examples (not that they work for me) is they are calculating the information before the completion handler.

Comment: You can use KVO (`[_currentAsset addObserver:self
                  forKeyPath:@"duration" ` + `observeValueForKeyPath` )

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Loading an `AVAsset` is asynchronous operation. You should wait until it will be prepared. The most efficient way to "wait" is using KVO.

In your class, let it be `ViewController`, make `AVAsset` the member and call your `trimmingFunc` somewhere:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var currentAsset: AVAsset?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.trimmingFunc()
    }
....
```

In your `trimmingFunc`, **subscribe** for notifications of `currentAsset`:

```
func trimmingFunc() {

    let audioURL = URL.init(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Be That Man", ofType: "mp3")!)

    print("audioURL=\(audioURL)")
    currentAsset = AVAsset(url: audioURL)
    let options = NSKeyValueObservingOptions([.new, .old, .initial, .prior])
    currentAsset!.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "duration", options: options, context: nil)
}
```

To receive that notifications, override function `observeValue` of `NSObject`:

```
override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {

    print("\(keyPath): \(change?[.newKey])")

    print(CMTimeGetSeconds(currentAsset!.duration)) //This is printing 0
}
```

So, if you had file "Be That Man.mp3" in resources, after few milliseconds you would see  duration = 202.945306122449

Full code of ViewController is [here](https://gist.github.com/gatamar/45fdac332a69bdca7a795291c03ead34).